# Windows GnuPG - GPG - Smart Card Status - Not Detecting Yubikey

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, yubikey

I have a Yubikey 4.  On a Windows 7 64 bit machine I installed Gpg4Win which includes GnugPG.  I was able to successfully import public keys.  I plugged in the Yubikey 4 and Windows correctly identified and installed the proper drivers.
However, issuing the ' gpg --card-status ' command results in:

gpg: selecting openpgp failed: No such device

gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device

This is strange behavior as I can see the Yubikey information using the Yubikey Personalization Tools (name, serial number, etc).

I have confirmed in Windows Services that "Smart Card" service is running.  I have also ran 'scdaemon.exe --server -v' and it says "smartcard server ready" and I also tried "gpg-agent --server -v" and it says "OK Pleased to meet you".  When I run the gpg --card-status command it doesn't reflect any verbose in those command prompts.

Any ideas on what would be causing this?  Yubikey personalization tools and neo manager can detect and read the Yubikey but GPG cannot.

EDIT:
I did the same steps on a different Windows 7 64 bit machine and it works (download gpg4win, import public keys, insert Yubikey and type in gpg --card-status and it loads stubs.   So this seems to be a local issue on the local machine, so what services or what tools exist to diagnose the issue on the original machine where it doesn't read the card (but Windows does).  I also tried opensc and it detects the Yubikey as well, but gpg does not.

Comment: When adding YubiKey, I had two smartcard readers on my system.
( the original and the Yubikey)
Disabling the other one solved this error.

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether this will help... But I bumped into this question when trying to solve a similar issue, and thought this might help: https://superuser.com/questions/1343569/scdaemon-wont-detect-yubikey-on-windows-10/1343581#1343581

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old thread, but since Google brought me here the 1st time I was searching the answer for this error message, I wanted to share a solution which worked for me.

My device has another smart-card reader. In the device manager I had to disable the other reader. Once it was disabled, gpg started to work properly. (You don't need to uninstall the device, and you can re-enable it when you want to use it)

Hope this helps someone.

[image: Disabled device]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue and just got to solve this using Windows 7 32 bit PC taking this considerations:

- Using remote desktop causes trouble.
- Installing "gpg4win" did not worked for me. instead I just installed "gnupg v 1.4.23".
- I executed the command like this: "C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG>gpg --card-status"
- Also as mentioned above I disabled any other card reader.
- Installed Yubikey mini driver "YubiKey-Minidriver-4.1.1.210-x86.msi"